 Implications of まあいいけど + いいなら in this situation
Appreciates some experts about Japanese who could help me understand exactly the implications of this dialogue while i'm reading a story! Here are my interpretations, fell free to correct if i was wrong.
1/まあいいけど :"Well I don't worry about my territory though"
2/いいなら: "If you not worry about your territory,then (don't call me here to do these trivial matters like order your clothes)"
A Supreme General/何進 of the Imperial court is having a war council meeting with other generals in the palace, then her sister/ also a consort of the Emperor (何太后) came in to tell her that the Emperor (空丹様/ 霊帝) want to meet the Supreme General at the palace's garden. It seems the Emperor - together with Chief Attendant of Emperor (趙忠) want to discuss with her about ordering tailored clothes for the Emperor.
何太后「……姉様。空丹様が、会議はまだ終わらないのかと言っているわよ」
何進「ああ、そうであった。……まったく、着物の誂えなど、余がおらずとも何とでもなるだろうにな」
何進「お待たせいたしました、主上様」
趙忠「……遅いですよ、何進殿。まったく、主上様のこと以上に大事な用事など、あるはずがないでしょうに」
何進「……主上様の版図を守るための、大将軍の執務ですゆえ」
霊帝「ふぅん。まあいいけど」
何進（いいならこんな事で呼びつけるんじゃない……暗君め）
趙忠「ああ、主上様。どちらの布もよくお似合いです。これでお着物を仕立てたら、主上様はどんなに美しくなることでしょう……！！」

A translation is like this:

まあいいけど。
Well, whatever.
いいならこんな事で呼びつけるんじゃない……
Whatever? Then don't summon me for something like this...

This "whatever" doesn't mean the emperor isn't interested in his territories. He is showing disinterest in 何進's excuse for being late. 何進 likely thought that, if the Emperor wasn't even concerned about the reason for being late, this matter about clothes wasn't important in the first place.
